# Which product is ordered most frequently?

Tags: sql, teradata

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM OrderLine_T
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY COUNT(ProductID) DESC
```

I'm ordering the products like this but `LIMIT` or `ROWNUM` is not functioning for some reason. I need to have a query with only the single most frequently ordered product. Im Using Teradata and the database name is db_pvfc10_big . Im sorry for the confusing question its my first question and im a beginner in using SQL

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: why isn't limt working (sounds more interesting that)

Comment: Im Using Teradata and the database name is db_pvfc10_big . Im sorry for the confusing question its my first question and im a beginner in using SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try including the count(ProductID) in the select statement. Some sql databases use the keyword "top" instead of "limit". So if you're using one of those (like Teradata sql for example), do the following:

```
select top 1 ProductID, count(ProductID)
from OrderLine_T
group by ProductID
order by 2 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` keyword is a MySQL-specific extension to the standard.

And `ROWNUM` is a pseudo column specific to Oracle.

So there are definitely "some reasons" that you might observe `LIMIT` and `ROWNUM` as "not functioning".

The question doesn't indicate *which* RDBMS is being used... MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Teradata, etc.

(NOTE: using "not functioning" as the only description of the behavior you observe is rather imprecise.

The description doesn't indicate whether the execution of the query is returning an error of some kind, or if the query is executing and returning a resultset that isn't expected.

The statement(s) you describe as "not functioning" aren't even shown.

One ANSI-standard SQL approach to getting a result is getting that "maximum" value using the standard `MAX()` aggregate. One way to do that is using an inline view. For example:

```
  SELECT MAX(s.cnt) AS max_cnt
    FROM ( SELECT COUNT(t.productid) AS cnt
             FROM orderline_t t
            GROUP BY t.productid
         ) s
```

That can also be used as an inline view...

```
  SELECT MAX(q.productid)
    FROM ( SELECT MAX(s.cnt) AS max_cnt
             FROM ( SELECT COUNT(t.productid) AS cnt
                      FROM orderline_t t
                     GROUP BY t.productid
                   ) s
         ) r
    JOIN ( SELECT p.productid 
                , COUNT(p.productid) AS cnt
             FROM orderline_t p
            GROUP BY p.product_id
         ) q
      ON q.cnt = r.max_cnt
```

Note that if there are two or more products that are ordered the same "maximum" number of times, this query will return just one of those productid.

This should work in most relational databases.

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

But this example should help explain why most RDBMS offer extensions to the SQL standard, which often make for simpler queries.

MySQL "... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1"

SQL Server "SELECT TOP 1 ..."

etc.

Comment: Im Using Teradata and the database name is db_pvfc10_big . Im sorry for the confusing question its my first question and im a beginner in using SQL